# liquibase: can you specify "after column" with liquibase addColumn?

Tags: mysql, database-migration, liquibase, changeset

Is there a way to write a liquibase addColumn changeset so it generates sql like

```
ALTER TABLE xxx ADD COLUMN yyy AFTER zzz;
```

I mean, is there a way to add an equivalent of "after column zzz" in liquibase jargon?

Comment: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With Liquibase 3.1 there are new "afterColumn", "beforeColumn" and "position" attributes on the column tag.

The documentation at http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html was just updated to include them.

Comment: These column attributes aren't working yet. Relevant bug report: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1745

Answer (score 16):

Until [this](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1745) is fixed, you can use [modifySql](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html).

```
<changeSet id="1-1" author="david">
    <comment>Add column field to example table</comment>
    <addColumn tableName="example">
        <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(50)" defaultValue="">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </addColumn>

    <!-- Use modifySql so we can insert it in the desired position -->
    <modifySql>
        <append value=" AFTER some_column"/>
    </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: BTW `append` fails on H2 when field has unique constraint (because in this case 2 `ALTER TABLE` commands will be generated).